# (Swift) Pass data into another viewController using callBack function

Tags: swift, uitableview, callback, closures, swift5

Situation:

I have a tableView with many cells. Every cell has got the same type/class and every cell has got a toggleSwitch.
One of the cells, or more precisely cell in section 2, row 0, when it's switch is toggled, need to update a variable of type bool to true/false(if switch is on => true). That variable is in a second VC.
With the code below, doesn't matter which of the cells is tapped, it prints `switch is on/switch is off`, but I need that only for a mentioned above cell. 
Cell's class:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelCell: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var cellSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func toggleSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
    if cellSwitch.isOn == true {
        print("switch is on")
    }
    else {
        print("switch is off")
    }
}
```

In cellForRowAt:

```
case (2,0):
        cell.labelCell.text = "Shuffled"
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let cardVC = (mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardViewController") as! CardViewController)
        //place for condition, if switch is on/off, put the true/false to secondVC.shuffle
        cardVC.shuffle = true
```

My question is how my callback function should look like, I have no experience with them. And how to check if this (2,0) cell is tapped?

Comment: when are your presenting your `CardViewController ` ? in didSelectRowAt?

Comment: No, on a buttonClick. Button is under the tableView

Comment: you can solve this via notification or delegate pattern or you put the data in a global variable (single source of truth) where all other get their data from.

Comment: Have you tried Protocol and Delegate for this ?

Comment: No, never did anything with them. If I dont find a solution, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this callBack function into your tableViewCell file as showing bellow.

```
var callback:((Bool) -> Void)?

@IBAction func toggleSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
    if cellSwitch.isOn == true {
        print("switch is on")
        callback?(true)
    }
    else {
        print("switch is off")
        callback?(false)
    }
}
```

---

you can get row tap using **didSelectRowAt** method of **UITableViewDelegate**.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
if indexPath.section == 2 {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // the tapped detect of (2,0)
    }
}
}
```

---

And you can get your callBack tap action of UISwitch from **cellForRowAt** method like show bellow.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   if indexPath.section == 2 {
      var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCell") as! YourCell
      if indexPath.row == 0 {
          //here you can write your callBack closure & your UISwitch's value will retrived here
          cell.callback = { [unowned self] check in
              cardVC.shuffle = check

          }
      }
   }
}
```