# How to expand cell when button inside cell is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm newer in xcode and swift and i found a guide for expand cell when the entire cell is pressed.
Now i wanna expand the cell when the button inside the cell is pressed.

I have this in my view controller :

```
//datasource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView.tag == 100 {
        return nameArr.count
    }else{
        return prova.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if tableView.tag == 100 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = nameArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.expand.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
        }else{
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsideTableViewCell") as! InsideTableViewCell
                cell.lblInsideName.text = prova[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //se la cella è selezionata e deve essere tirata ancora giù ritorna 243 che sarebbe il valore della cella + l'immagine dentro da mostrare
    if  selectedIndex == indexPath.row && isCollapsed == true && tableView.tag == 100 {
            return 375
        }else {
            //altrimenti se è gia collassata e ripremiamo sulla cella ritorna 50 e quindi richiude la cella
            return 96
        }
}


//delegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
        if self.isCollapsed == false {
            self.isCollapsed = true
        }else{
            self.isCollapsed = false
        }
    }else{
        self.isCollapsed = true
    }
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    //tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

But i don't know ho to do that.

In my viewController now i have this variable :

```
var selectedIndex = -1 //tell me which cell i pressed
var isCollapsed = false // tell if the cell is already collapsed
```

Comment: Do you want to toggle your `isCollapsed` from the cell button?

Comment: yes i want to collaps the cell when the button inside that cell is pressed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226353/swift-pass-data-into-another-viewcontroller-using-callback-function/60227075#60227075 , you can get cell's buttonclick in cellForRowAt. check this. & apply logic for increase cell height into callback closure(in cellForRowAt method).

Comment: is this all the table cell or just specific ones?

Answer (score 0):

You should update the table view after changing the height:
`tableView.reloadData()`.

You can do it by sending info about that action to the view controller using delegates.

1) You should save a state of your cells. You can store it in the cell model:

```
class YourCellModel {
    var isExpanded = false
}
```

2) You should create a delegate protocol:

```
protocol YourCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func buttonPressed()
}
```

3) Add properties for the cell delegate and the cell model. Also you should add a function `buttonPressed`:

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: YourCellDelegate?
    var model: YourCellModel?
    //...

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
        model?.isExpanded = true
        delegate?.buttonPressed()
    }

}
```

4) You should store cell models in the view controller: {

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    var cellModels: [YourCellModel] = []
    //...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cellModels = Array(repeating: YourCellModel(), count: <count of cells, maybe it is a prova.count>)
    }

}
```

5) Setup cell models and delegates to the cells in `cellForItem`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let model = cellModels[indexPath.row]
    if tableView.tag == 100 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell
        cell.lblName.text = nameArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.expand.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.model = model
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InsideTableViewCell") as! InsideTableViewCell
        cell.lblInsideName.text = prova[indexPath.row]
        cell.model = model
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

6) Update `heightForItem`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let model = cellModels[indexPath.row]
    if model.isExpanded {
        return 375
    } else {
        return 96
    }
}
```

7) Your view controller should implement `YourCellDelegate`:

```
extension YourViewController: YourCellDelegate {
    func buttonPressed() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: but this collaps all the cell in my table view

Comment: @matteoantonucci Yeah, you can use a delegate for that. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: i update the question with the code that i have in my view controller, how can i pass the row that i have to expand when the button in that row is pressed ?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what i have to put inside the func button pressed ?

Comment: @matteoantonucci I added an example. After changing the height, you should update your table view.

Comment: @matteoantonucci Oh, sorry, I see you don't save info that the cell was expanded.

Comment: for me it didn't work i added the protocol in my tableViewCell.swift file and inside the protocol use button click function but in the ViewController when i do cell.delegate = self it return me that i haven't any delegate inside my uitableviewcell class

Comment: @matteoantonucci Are you sure you added property `weak var delegate: YourCellDelegate?` in your cell class?

Comment: @matteoantonucci I missed the implementation of function `buttonPressed` in your cell class. But this expands all cells in your table view how you said, it is true. I should update my answer to solve it.

Comment: func YourCellDelegate: AnyObject this isn't work for me

Comment: @matteoantonucci My mistake. It should be `protocol YourCellDelegate: AnyObject` (

Comment: what is model.height ?

Comment: @matteoantonucci model is an instance of class `SomeCellModel`. You should store states of your cells (e.g., some cell is expanded or not) in the view controller. All cell models should be stored in the cell in a specific index path. I tried to explain it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60447409/uisearchcontroller-indexpath-doesnt-change-with-original-array/60447774#60447774

Comment: @matteoantonucci I added the code with cell models, but maybe someone will show you an easier way.

Comment: when i do cell.delegate = self it return me cannot assign type ViewController to type MainTableViewCellDelegate

Comment: @matteoantonucci It means `ViewController` doesn't implement protocol `MainTableViewCellDelegate`. It is a 7th item on the list: `7) Your view controller should implement YourCellDelegate:`

Answer (score 0):

**Modify the data source to change it**

And of course the data source can be more complex it can be an object that contains whether or not to open the property

```
let nameArr:[Bool] = [false, false, false]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.nameArr[indexPath.row] = !self.nameArr[indexPath.row]
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let isshow = self.nameArr[indexPath.row]
    if isshow {
        return 375
    } else {
        return 69
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a clouser in cell and call it when you press the button in your cell

in your cell define:

```
var buttonClicked: (() -> Void)?
```

in your cell button call this clouser

```
func buttonPressAction() {
   buttonClicked?()

}
```

in your cellForRow method change it like this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView.tag == 100 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell
        cell.buttonClicked = { [weak self] in
            if self.isCollapsed == false {
                self.isCollapsed = true
            } else{
                self.isCollapsed = false
            }
        }else{
            self.isCollapsed = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and where i have to return my cell ?

Comment: the other stuff of your cell is the same as your code, I didn't implement all the code, just show the sample, do the rest as you have done in your code